# Get optionset text from OData query in CRM web api

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

```
https://example.com/crm/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=custom_optionset
```

The above query selects all values in an optionset field in CRM. The return data looks something like this:

```
{
    {
        "@odata.etag":"W/\"112607639\"","custom_optionset":285960000,"accountid":"a08f0bd1-e2c4-e111-8c9a-00155d0aa573"
    },
    {
        "@odata.etag":"W/\"112615384\"","custom_optionset":285960010,"accountid":"a18f0bd1-e2c4-e111-8c9a-00155d0aa573"
    }
}
```

I don't want the value of the optionset. I want the associated text label.
How do I get this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get optionset text using webapi, use below snippet in request header.

```
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue");
```

This will return the picklist text similar to lookup FormattedValue.

[image]

Entire code example:

```
function retrieveEntity(entityName, Id, columnSet) {
    var serverURL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var Query = entityName + "(" + Id + ")" + columnSet;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", serverURL + "/api/data/v8.2/" + Query, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */ ) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
                if (data != null {
                        alert(data["_primarycontactid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]); //for lookup text
                        alert(data["paymenttermscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]); //for optionset text
                    }
                } else {
                    var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                    alert(error.message);
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();
    }
```

[Reference](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=2077).

Answer (score 3):

If you use Jason Lattimer's CRM RESTBuilder Solution, it creates a query like this, which includes the header `req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");`:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts(674D7FDC-47AE-E711-8108-5065F38A3BA1)?$select=accountid,industrycode", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            var accountid = result["accountid"];
            var industrycode = result["industrycode"];
            var industrycode_formatted = result["industrycode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

And the result includes the option set label:

```
{
@odata.context:"https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(accountid,industrycode)/$entity",
@odata.etag:"W/"1959756"",
accountid:"674d7fdc-47ae-e711-8108-5065f38a3ba1",
industrycode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue:"Accounting",
industrycode:1
}
```

Comment: Is there any official reference for this?

Answer (score 3):

I find it easiest to use [XrmQuery](http://delegateas.github.io/Delegate.XrmDefinitelyTyped/xrmquery-web.html) for calling the Web API in CRM (full disclosure: I work for the company that developed this). No manual fiddling with headers and XMLHttpRequests is needed, and you get full strongly typed support for the entities and fields in your own CRM.

As an example, retrieving a specific account and selecting the `industrycode` field looks as follows:

```js
    XrmQuery.retrieve(a => a.accounts, "5B86C6EB-DE6D-E611-80DF-C4346BADF080")
        .select(a => [a.industrycode])
        .includeFormattedValues()
        .execute(a => {
            console.log("Industry is: " + a.industrycode_formatted);
        });
```

Adding `.includeFormattedValues()` automatically gives you access to a field simply called `industrycode_formatted`.

For an account with the following optionset value: 
[image: Industry in CRM]

The code above will return:

> Industry is: Broadcasting Printing and Publishing